# Review Tag Repositioner

Tags: script, posts, review

### About:

This userscript clones the tags and adds them to the top of the post when working in the review queue.  This is in response to a [feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311043/show-tags-on-top-when-reviewing-questions) on Meta Stack Overflow.

[image]

### Installation:

[Install](https://github.com/enki-code/UserScripts/raw/master/review-tag-reposition.user.js)

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Tag Reposition
// @description  Repositions Tags at top of question in review queue
// @namespace    https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454538/
// @author       ᴉʞuǝ
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/review/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/review/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/review/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/review/*
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/review/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/review/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/review/*
// @exclude      *://api.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      *://blog.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      *://blog.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude      *://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      *://elections.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      *://stackexchange.com/*
// @run-at       document-end
// ==/UserScript==
(function($) {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
        if(isReview(settings.url)){
            var $tags,
                $review = $(".review-content"),
                $title = $("<h2/>", {text: "Tags", style:"display: inline-block; margin-right: 5px;"});

            if(isEditReview(window.location.href)){
                $tags = $("a.post-tag:first").parent().clone();
            } else {
                $tags = $(".post-taglist").clone();
            }

            $tags.addClass("subheader").css("border-bottom", "none");
            $tags.prepend($title);
            $review.prepend($tags);
        } 
    });

    function isReview(url){
        var result = false;
        if(~url.indexOf("review/task-reviewed") || ~url.indexOf("review/next-task")){
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    function isEditReview(url){
        return url.indexOf("edits") === -1 ? false : true;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: For js noobs like me follow [this installation instruction](https://superuser.com/questions/252046/how-do-i-install-a-userscript). Greasemonkey didn't work for whatever reason, but Tampermonkey did. Thanks for creating this script, which makes life easier.

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The script is working except in the **Suggested Edits** review queue, since the `.subheader h2:first` does not exist for that queue.

Can you please add some workaround for the **Suggested Edits** review queue?

Comment: Its working fine except the _tag only change_ edits. [Sample](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11053896). Here it doesn't show the `rendered output` and `markdown`. This case need to be handle.

Comment: After the fix it's working as expected. Cheers.

Comment: Since I don't have enough reputation _(currently less than 3K)_, but I find a sample (from SO meta - audit failed questions) for [Close vote](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8793978), [Re open](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1579500) and tested. Everything looking good.